# How to enable try-catch in clang libtooling?

Tags: c++, clang, libtooling

I wanted to use try catch statement in clang libtooling,but by default it is taking compiling options as `-fno-rtti and -fno-exceptions`

If I use the try-catch statement in clang libtooling , It is throwing error message

`samplecode`

```
try
{



}
catch(std::exception &e)
{


}
```

`Cannot Use try with Exception Disabled`.

How to enable try catch for clang libtooling program?

Comment: A call within the scope of a try statement can potentially raise an exception. In those circumstances, the LLVM C++ front-end replaces the call with an invoke instruction. Unlike a call, the invoke has two potential continuation points. https://llvm.org/docs/ExceptionHandling.html#try-catch ` __cxa_throw.`

Comment: I found the answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411798/enabling-rtti-for-clang-tool